# How do I change the separator of extraParams in an ExtJS store proxy?

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I'm stuck with a problem related to the extraParams of an ExtJS store.. I need to change the default params separator & to a customized ; since the web service I'm accessing doesn't respond to &.

Is there a way to change the separator?

Bests, Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround on the Sencha forums:

```
yourStore.proxy.url = 'your/url/' + yourParameter + ';.....';
```

With this line, before loading the store, it's possible to go around the extraParams and still pass them directly to the used proxy using the url field.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in to ExtJS to allow customisation of the parameter separator - the use of '&' is a de-facto standard, after all.

However, you can change the default behaviour if you need to by overriding `Ext.Object.toQueryString`

```
Ext.define('Ext.override.CustomQueryString', {
  override: 'Ext.Object',
  toQueryString: function() {
    var queryString = this.callParent(arguments);
    return queryString.replace('&', ':');
  }
})
```

Something like that would change behaviour globally. This may or may not be a good thing to do.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your comment. Sadly I can't change it globally and I know that & is the standard but I can't change a webservice I didn't wrote.

Comment: Then eschewing the use of the query parameters and hardcoding it into the URL, as per your answer, is the way to go.